# What controls the speed of input characters to windows NOTEPAD

Tags: windows, notepad

when i keep pressing Keyboard key 'A' at NOTEPAD, it input about 25 'A' to notepad per second, what controls the speed of input characters ?

Answer (score 2):

Notepad is a giant EditBox.  It's controlled by the [system setting](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_kbd_repeat_rate.mspx?mfr=true).

To read or write this value programmatically, use [SystemParametersInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Check out the section for `Input Parameters`.